# Whats does d mean in a journal citation?

Tags: reference

I would like to cite a journal and I was hoping to find page numbers, instead it is formatted like this:

> BMJ. 2011; 343: d5094.

Does the 'd' indicate the page or something else?

Comment: It's (Publication. Year; Volume: **Issue**.) "Issue" refers to the whole document (article).

Comment: See also: [academia.se]

Answer (score 2):

This is the [doi number](http://www.doi.org/)

DOI stands for "Digital Object Identifier"

Here's a [BMJ citation guide](http://www.citethisforme.com/guides/bmj/how-to-cite-a-journal)

> Template:
>   1 Author Surname Author Initial. Title. Publication Title Year Published;Volume number:Pages Used. doi:DOI Number

So your citation is for:
Publication: BMJ
Year: 2011
Volume: 353
Digital Object Identifier: 5094

Comment: I'm not sure that's what it is. The whole "d5094" is the number given by the BMJ.